# Reloading cucumber.js steps with gulp-watch and gulp-develop-server

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, cucumberjs

I'm trying to use the following gulpfile.js in order to watch for changes, restart my server, and re-run my tests (cucumber.js). Changing a cucumber spec, or a file in my application both successfully trigger the process. However, the updated content of the specs is ignored! It's like the spec is cached. How can I ensure the latest specs are executed?

File content:

```js
"use strict";
var gulp = require( "gulp" );
var cucumber = require( "gulp-cucumber" );
var watch = require( "gulp-watch" );
var server = require( 'gulp-develop-server' );

gulp.task( "cukes", function( done ) {

    return gulp.src( "specs/**/*.feature" ).pipe( cucumber( {

        "steps" : "specs/steps/**/*.js,support/*_hooks.js",
        "format" : "pretty"

    } ) );

} );


gulp.task( "test", [ "server:start", "cukes" ] );

gulp.task( "server:start", function() {

    server.listen( { path: "./index.js" } );

} );

gulp.task( "watch", [ "server:start" ], function() {

    watch( [ "lib/**/*", "specs/**/*" ], function() {

        server.restart( function() {

            setTimeout( function() { gulp.start( "cukes" ); }, 500 );

        } );

    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 3):

Node modules are cached in `require.cache`, so you need to reset the cache to not include what cucumber requires.  You can do this by saving `Object.keys(require.cache)` just before calling `watch()`, and then deleting any new keys from `require.cache` before starting the "cukes" task.  Something like this should probably work:

`gulp.task( "watch", [ "server:start" ], function() {
    var originalKeys = Object.keys(require.cache);
    watch( [ "lib/**/*", "specs/**/*" ], function() {
        server.restart( function() {
            var newKeys = Object.keys(require.cache);
            while (newKeys.length > originalKeys.length) {
                delete require.cache[newKeys.pop()];
            }
            setTimeout( function() { gulp.start( "cukes" ); }, 500 );
        } );
    } );
} );`

(It would probably also be a good idea to add something like this to gulp-cucumber via a pull request.)

Comment: FYI https://github.com/vgamula/gulp-cucumber/issues/13 was closed specifically for this a couple of years ago. Quote from the readme in the commit: '**You have to set `options.steps` and `options.support` for preventing caching these files by require.cache**'. This didn't work for me using typescript (but probably would work for others). I ended up using the require.cache approach here. Thanks for your post!